# Shared wishlist just displays html

Tags: email, email-templates, html, wishlist, share-wishlist

I'm trying to setup up the share wishlist feature, all of the admin settings are correct but the email just sends through a load of html!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to fix it. The email template was using `{{var items}}` but changing it to `{{var items|raw}}` sorts it.